# wxPython DirDialog does not scroll to selected folder

Tags: python, windows, wxpython

I'm using wxPython DirDialog and it seems to have a bug.
When launching the dialog I specify a default path (defaultPath).
That path is being selected by the dialog but the dialog is not scrolled to the selected path.

Instead the dialog is scrolled to the top of the dialog.

This leaves the user to scroll A LOT down to reach the default path.
Very inconvenient.

Any way to correct this?

Using:
Python 2.6.5
wxPython 2.8.12.1
Windows 8.1

Comment: What exactly are you passing it in `defaultPath`?

Comment: Just a normal absolute path.
If I scroll down I DO see it selected in the dialog

Comment: You mean `C:\Foo\bar\zoo\file.txt` ?

Comment: No. I pass a folder like this:
C:\Foo\bar\zoo

Answer (score 0):

It may not be any consolation but with Python 2.7.12 Wx '3.0.2.0 gtk2 (classic)' on Linux, the following works as it should. Check if you are doing something different.

```
def OnSelect_dir(self,event):
    dialog = wx.DirDialog (None,defaultPath=self.client_dir.GetValue(), message = 'Pick a directory.' )
    if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
       self.client_dir.SetValue(dialog.GetPath())
    else:
       pass
    dialog.Destroy()
```

It works is I hard code `defaultPath='/home/rolf'` as well.

Comment: Indeed. Of no consolation. :) I do the same

Comment: commiserations :(

Answer (score 0):

Well apparently if I exclude the style "wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE" then it works just fine.

So this works:

`style = wx.DD_DIR_MUST_EXIST`

But this doesn't focus the dialog properly on the defaultPath:

`style = wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE | wx.DD_DIR_MUST_EXIST`

I guess it must be a bug somewhere